# Xamarin.Forms app randomly crashes on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms.listview

am observing an issue with Xamarin.Forms application on Android. Generally it works fine, but randomly it crashes with a message like

crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.onMeasure
PlatformRenderer.java, line 63
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: View with id -1: crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.FlyoutPageRenderer#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()

or

androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure
ContentFrameLayout.java, line 145
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View with id -1: crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()

The navigation scheme is master-detail (using FlyoutPage class rather than the obsolete MasterDetailPage class), there are some Syncfusion controls (listview, toggle button), AndroidX packages.

It is impossible to replicate on will, I can see these errors only in application telemetry logs.

Any ideas where such issue may come from?

thanks

Jiri

Answer (score 0):

You could force the call of the setMeasuredDimension inside your onMeasure() method to fix the issue.

```
 @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    shortestDistance = getMeasuredWidth() / 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't override the OnMeasure method anywhere in my code...

Comment: Have you try to override? Normally, it would fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I simply do not have any OnMeasure method implementation in my code.